# JavaScript this issue with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, this, setinterval

I'm trying to call a portion of code in a class over and over again at every second,

```
update() {
    for (let entity of this.entities) {
      if (entity instanceof Alien) {
        entity.y += 1;
        renderAliens(entity, this.context);
      }
    } 
  }
```

this is the code I am trying to call inside of my Game object using
`setInterval(newGame.update(),1000)`, however when I attempt to do this it errors saying that `Uncaught TypeError: this.entities is undefined`, I understand that this is due to a scope issue with this and setinterval, yet I am unsure how to use bind to solve the issue

edit: here's the whole piece of relevant code

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.entities = [];
    this.context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  }
  start() {
    this.entities.push(new Ship(0, 400));
    this.entities.push(new Alien(1, 0));
    this.entities.push(new Alien(20, 0));
    this.entities.push(new Alien(40, 0));
  }
  render() {
    for (let entity of this.entities) {
      if (entity instanceof Alien) {
        renderAliens(entity, this.context);
      } else if (entity instanceof Ship) {
        renderShip(entity, this.context);
      }
    }
  }
  update() {
    for (let entity of this.entities) {
      if (entity instanceof Alien) {
        entity.y += 20;
        renderAliens(entity, this.context);
      }
    }
  }

  endGame() {}
}

const newGame = new Game();
newGame.start();
newGame.render();
let t = setInterval(newGame.update, 1000);
```

Comment: Could you maybe share more of your code? Would make it easier

Comment: added the whole piece of relevant code

Comment: Please refer this link https://javascript.info/object-methods#this-in-methods for better understanding of `this` and you can know what was wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- use `.bind()`. This binds `this` to the newGame instance

  ```js
  setInterval(newGame.update.bind(newGame), 1000);
  ```
- define a callback function:

  ```js
  setInterval(function(){
    newGame.update();
  }, 1000);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the interval like:

```js
const intervalRef = setInterval(() => { newGame.update() }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare the interval in your constructor? This way, you will avoid any context issues.

```
constructor() {
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.entities = [];
    this.context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000); // Here
  }
```